# canvas.height is not changing for IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

In Java script I am changing the height and width of the HTML5 canvas. It works in Mozila, Chrome, opera and safari, But it is not working in IE9. Can any body tell me what I am doing wrong, do I need to set any property?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:-
HTML:-

```
<body onload="Load();">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
```

Javascript:-

```
function Load(){
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
     img=new Image();
     img.src= "data:image/bmp;base64,"+respObj.respData; //Adding bmp image header
     img.onload = function(){
     canvas.width = 300;
     canvas.height = 500;
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
}
```

CSS:-

```
.canvas{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin : 0px 35px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with php?

Comment: I think PHP people may also help So I added this tag

Comment: There is no HTML code for your canvas. No java Script function that you tried. How can one tell which property are you missing?

Comment: I have updated my question with code, please find it

Comment: [Seems to be working fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu6ex/). Could you fix your code, or better, provide us with a JSFiddle example?

Comment: Even with your updated HTML/CSS etc., it [seems to be working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ekfe/) (although your ID in the example was wrong, and you missed to close the onload function)...

Comment: I modified my questions, Actually I have removed some of my project code there. And yes even here also it works fine. But my question is while my code is running perfectly in other browsers then y not working in IE9

Comment: will context.clearRect and  context.drawImage change the height and width property of the canvas?

Comment: never ever set height and width in Style script as it will override to its default values for height and width to 150 and 300 respectively

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It is working in IE9, Firefox, Chrome :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style language="css/text">
    .canvas{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin : 0px 35px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<body onload="Load();">
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
            <input type="button" onClick="change()"/>
</body>

<script>
     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Load(){
     img=new Image();
     //img.src= "data:image/bmp;base64,"+respObj.respData; //Adding bmp image header

     canvas.width = 300;
     canvas.height = 500;
     context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
     context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     //context.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function change() {
     canvas.width = 100;
     canvas.height = 100;
    context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
You can accept your own answer tomorrow
(click on this box to dismiss)
 

I found the issue with my canvas. It was the issue with style. I have removed the height and width setting from the style script. Because of it, the canvas height and width was overriding to its default values i.e. 150 and 300 as height and width respectively. Any way Thanks for your kind responses Amber :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my canvas. It was the issue with style. I have removed the height and width setting from the style script. Because of it, the canvas height and width was overriding to its default values i.e. 150 and 300 as height and width respectively.